# Why is this reference of a pointer a rvalue?

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, rvalue

I have the following base and inherited classes:

```
// Abstract base class Manager.
class Manager
{
public:
  Manager(Task*& _task);
protected:
  // Reference of a pointer to the current task.
  Task*& task;
};

// Abstract base class Task.
class Task
{
  virtual task_rcodes_t run() = 0;
protected:
  uint8_t task_id;
};

// Still abstract class Special_Task.
class Special_Task : public Task
{
public:
  Special_Task();
};

// Class Special_Manager.
class Special_Manager : public Manager
{
public:
  Special_Manager();
protected:
  // Pointer to the current special task.
  Special_Task* task;
};
```

The idea is to allow the task pointer to be 0 in order to detect that no current task is running. In order to have common access to the Task and Special_Task pointers they are passed by reference to pointer.

Why do I get the error message:
*"invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Task*&' from an rvalue of type 'Special_Task*'"
in combination with:
*"Symbol 'Manager' could not be resolved"*

for the Constructor of the Special_Manager:

```
// Constructor Manager
Manager::Manager(Task*& _task) : task (_task)
{}

// Constructor Special_Manager
Special_Manager::Special_Manager() : Manager(task), task (0)
{}
```

Since Special_Task* task is a normal (pointer) variable, I don't see why it is considered a rvalue?

Thank you!

Comment: Because it isn't an lvalue, because you can't assign to references.

Comment: What's that `Special_Manager();` inside class `Manager_Special`???

Comment: That is the Constructor. I corrected the typing error in the class name.

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't have produced a proper [MCVE] in this case. Why didn't you remove parts of the code that weren't relevant to the question? Did you try to reduce this to a minimal testcase?

Comment: Example of suitable MCVE: https://godbolt.org/g/YVxyKH - see how this can be compiled to give (more-or-less) the error you're asking about? I'd love to know how you got the exact error that you claim you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since Special_Task* task is a normal (pointer) variable, I don't see why it is considered a rvalue?

Any lvalue can be converted to an rvalue via an implicit conversion. `task` is an lvalue because it is "the name of a variable ... in scope" (see [cppreference on value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)), and it is converted to an rvalue in your example.

But the whole lvalue/rvalue thing is largely a red herring in this case. The problem is that you are trying to assign a pointer of one type to a pointer reference of a different type, as the error message says:

*invalid initialization of non-const reference **of type 'Task*&'** from an rvalue **of type 'Special_Task*'***

(as an aside, I'd love to know exactly what compiler/code gave you that message. All versions of gcc that I've tried give instead: *invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Task*&' from an rvalue of type 'Task*'*).

Even though `Special_Task` is a derived type of `Task`, you cannot do this. Their respective pointer types are not subtypes; a `Special_Task *` is not a`Task *` and therefore a `Task *&`-variable can not be assigned a `Special_Task *`. (Some confusion can result from the fact that `Special_Task *` can be implicitly converted to a `Task *`, however, it's important to note that in this case the resulting pointer is an rvalue, not an lvalue, which explains the latter error message).

To illustrate why you cannot assign a `Special_Task *` to a `Task *&` variable, consider the following example:

```
// Other_Task is a second derived class of Task:
class Other_Task : public Task { /* ...  */ }

Special_Task st;
Special_Task *p = &st; // ok, p points to st

Task *& tp = p; // if it were allowed: tp references p

Other_Task ot;
tp = &ot;       // now, p points to ot - which is the wrong type
```

The above example shows why can't assign a `Special_Task *` to a `Task *&` variable directly. Because of this, in your code the `Special_Task *` is implicitly converted to a `Task *` and becomes an rvalue, which also cannot be assigned to a non-const reference. The example also shows why a `const` reference would be ok: it would prevent the assignment which causes `p` to point to an object of the wrong type.

Back to your problem: seeing as there is no need for `task` in `Manager` to be a reference, the simple fix is to change its declaration to a simple pointer:

```
Task* task;
```

And change the constructor:

```
Manager(Task* _task);
```

An alternative solution, though not one I'd recommend, would be to change the type to a `const` reference:

```
Task * const & task;

Manager(Task* const & _task);
```

Oh, and one more thing:

```
Special_Manager::Special_Manager() : Manager(task), task (0)
```

This passes the uninitialized value of `task` to the `Manager` constructor and *then* initialises `task` to 0. Instead you should write:

```
Special_Manager::Special_Manager() : Manager(0), task (0)
```

Comment: _"as the error message says"_ No, if you look at the question's Markdown, you'll see that that's a formatting error. OP did not escape the `*`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks, fixed. Had another missing `*` in the other error message as well (somehow) and I've fixed that as well. The written content applies to the actual error messages (i.e. the answer stands).

Comment: Changing to const wouldn't allow me to assign task = 0 during execution, right? Alternatively, I could use a normal Task pointer in Manager class as you stated, avoid an extra Special_Task pointer in Special_Manager and simply use reinterpretcast on the Task pointer if functionality from Special_Task is required!?

Comment: @nubert 1/ the `task(0)` isn't the problem (you should ignore the answer which you for some reason already accepted). `task(0)` is an initialisation of `task` in `Special_Manager`, which is of type `Special_Task *`, and this is perfectly allowed. You don't need to change that, and changing it to a `const *` won't help here. 2/ You _could_ use `reinterpret_cast` but the problem in general shows that your design is wrong: I would replace the `task` field in `Task` with a `getTask()` virtual member function which `Special_Task` can override. Ask another question if you need help.

Comment: @davmac the task_id is just required to identify the task, since I am running on a MCU that has no runtime information available. Furthermore, C++11 is not supported, so I guess changing my design to avoid the additional task pointer in Special_Task and hence avoid passing it as rvalue reference solves my issue. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
Special_Manager::Special_Manager() : Manager(task), task (0)
{}
```

`0` is considered an `rvalue` or an `int&&` that is cast to the type of `Task*&&`. This is possible because `0` is considered a valid form for a cast-able value to a pointer. But because the constructor only takes a `Task*&`, it cannot take the casted form of the value `0` and thus the compiler rejects the code.

If you were to make the constructor argument of the type `const Task*&`, the code would then compile, because `const Task*&` is compatible with the type of `Task*&&`.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the `0`. Remove `task (0)` from the code and you'll still get the same compiler error.

Comment: Also: _If you were to make the constructor argument of the type const Task*&_ - is wrong. `Task * const &` would be the appropriate type. The reference itself must be `const`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on davmac's answer:

- if `Y` is a subclass of `X`, then:

  - a *reference-to-`X`* can really refer to a `Y`. Similarly,
  - a *pointer-to-`X`* can point to a `Y`.

  However, the types *pointer-to-`X`* and *pointer-to-`Y`* are not themselves related in the same way `X` and `Y` are related, so

  - a *pointer-to-pointer-to-`X`* can't point to a *pointer-to-`Y`* (although the final *pointer-to-`X`* **could** point to a `Y`), and
  - a *reference-to-pointer-to-`X`* can't refer to a *pointer-to-`Y`* either.

Compare template instances, where despite `X` and `Y`'s relationship `std::vector<X>` and `std::vector<Y>` are not at all related.

---

Specifically, a *reference-to-pointer-to-`Task`* cannot refer to a *pointer-to-`Special_Task`*.